# Where can I find offline version of Docs?

Tags: aurelia

I usually use [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) when I don't have access to the internet but there is no Aurelia docset available. I also couldn't find [Aurelia Hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html) on github. Is there any way to get offline version of Aurelia docs?

Comment: I'm not sure about how this Dash works, but the Aurelia Hub is located at https://github.com/aurelia/framework/tree/master/doc/article/en-US

Comment: If you want to see the aurelia docs in dash, you might want to take a look at [dash-docset-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dash-docset-generator). I suppose you could use that to generate the docsets from the repos `doc` directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the docs are in the components respective repositories under the `doc/` directory in markdown format. For example, you can find the "framework" docs under `node_modules/aurelia-framework/doc/article` and the binding docs at `node_modules/aurelia-binding/doc/article`.

As far as I know, the code for the hub itself is not on github but you can use the raw markdown files that are also displayed in the hub. In fact, you might even find them to have more information then the hub from time to time, when the hub is not yet updated with the latest changes.